# Azure Devops: Manual Deployment to Environment using Pull Request build

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, devops

I am currently investigating Trunk Based Development using Git and Azure Devops. While it is nice that I can deploy code automatically to an environment after opening a pull request, my job has multiple pre-prod environments for testing. I would like to at least have a way to manually deploy my build via code from the outcome of a possible PR to a select environment. After testing is finished and it is approved I then want to take that same build and deploy it to another environment for further testing that was not available in the first environment. Is this possible?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to at least have a way to manually deploy my build via
>   code from the outcome of a possible PR to a select environment.

For this issue , when you create a  release , you can manually select pull request build version as artifact source for this release.

In the `Pipeline` section you can choose the stages for which you want to change the trigger from automated to manual. A manual deployment will be required for these stages.

[image]